# Netsuite: How do you let customers opt out of email blasts?

Tags: netsuite

I want to send my first email blast to customers via Netsuite. I've set them all up as soft opt-in. (we have a primarily offline business, so very few customers registered themselves) When I send that first email I definitely want to be transparent and provide a way for customers to opt out of future emails. I don't see anything in the email campaign setup about how to provide customers a way to opt out. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out. By default, the email campaigns include a place to opt out, which includes a link to a form that let's people explicitly opt in or opt out.

Comment: Thanks for the followup, Paul! I didn't know this either heh